# Call sequence of template function for sequence of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Let's imagine I have several template functions, e.g.:

```
template <int I> void f();
template <int I> void g();
template <int I> void h();
```

How can I call sequence of any of these functions for sequence of template parameters?

In other words, I need such behaviour:

```
{some template magic}<1, 5>(f); // This is pseudocode, I don't need exactly this format of calling.
```

unrolls into:

```
f<1>();
f<2>();
f<3>();
f<4>();
f<5>();
```

And I need the same method to work for every of my functions (not only for f, but for g and h too) without writing big awkward structure for every of these functions.

I can use C++11, and even already implemented in latest development gcc version C++1y/C++14 functionality (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html), e.g. polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: Do you even need templates if you're only using this for ints, or would you like to be able to use other types as well?

Comment: I need to use my enum type (which has size_t underlying type). So, for now I need only solution for integral types. Let's assume it's usual int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With C++1y features. Instead of calling the function directly and passing the template argument as, well, a template argument, you can create a lambda that takes a *function argument* which contains the template argument as part of its type. I.e.

```
f<42>();
[](std::integral_constant<int, 42> x) { f<x.value>(); }
[](auto x) { f<x.value>(); }
```

With this idea, we can pass the function template `f` around, when wrapped into such a polymorphic lambda. That's possible for any kind of overload set, one of the things you can't do with ordinary lambdas.

To call `f` with a sequence of template arguments, we'll need the common indices classes for the indices expansion trick. Those will be in the C++1y Standard Library. Coliru's clang++ compiler for example still uses an older libstdc++ which doesn't have them AFAIK. But we can write our own:

```
#include <utility>

using std::integral_constant;
using std::integer_sequence;       // C++1y StdLib
using std::make_integer_sequence;  // C++1y StdLib
// C++11 implementation of those two C++1y StdLib classes:
/*
template<class T, int...> struct integer_sequence {};
template<class T, int N, int... Is>
struct make_integer_sequence : make_integer_sequence<T, N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<class T, int... Is>
struct make_integer_sequence<T, 0, Is...> : integer_sequence<T, Is...> {};
*/
```

When we write `make_integer_sequence<int, 5>`, we'll get a type that's derived from `integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>`. From the latter type, we can deduce the indices:

```
template<int... Indices> void example(integer_sequence<int, Indices...>);
```

Inside this function, we have access to the indices as a parameter pack. We'll use the indices to call the lamba / function object `f` as follows (not the function template `f` from the question):

```
f( integral_constant<int, Indices>{} )...
// i.e.
f( integral_constant<int, 0>{} ),
f( integral_constant<int, 1>{} ),
f( integral_constant<int, 2>{} ),
// and so on
```

Parameter packs can only be expanded in certain contexts. Typically, you'd expand the pack as initializers (e.g. of a dummy array), as the evaluation of those is are guaranteed to be ordered (thanks, Johannes Schaub). Instead of an array, one could use a class type such as

```
struct expand { constexpr expand(...) {} };
// usage:
expand { pattern... };
```

A dummy array looks like this:

```
int expand[] = { pattern... };
(void)expand; // silence compiler warning: `expand` not used
```

Another tricky part is to deal with functions returning void as the pattern. If we combine a function call with a comma operator, we always get a result

```
(f(argument), 0) // always has type int and value 0
```

To break any existing overloaded comma operators, add a `void()`

```
(f(argument), void(), 0)
```

Finally, combine all the above to create magic:

```
template<int beg, class F, int... Is>
constexpr void magic(F f, integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    int expand[] = { (f(integral_constant<int, beg+Is>{}), void(), 0)... };
    (void)expand;
}

template<int beg, int end, class F>
constexpr auto magic(F f)
{
    //                                              v~~~~~~~v see below (*)
    return magic<beg>(f, make_integer_sequence<int, end-beg+1>{});
}
```

Usage example:

```
#include <iostream>
template<int N> void f() { std::cout << N << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    //magic<1, 5>( [](auto x) { f<decltype(x)::value>(); } );
    magic<1, 5>( [](auto x) { f<x.value>(); } );
}
```

---

(*) IMHO `end-beg+1` is bad practice. There's a reason why the StdLib works with half-open ranges of the form `[begin, end)`: The empty range simply is `[begin, begin)`. With the StdLib using half-open ranges, it might be inconsistent to use closed ranges here. (There's one exception in the StdLib I know of, it has to do with PRNGs and the maximum integer value.)

I'd suggest you'd design your `magic` interface to take half-open ranges, i.e.

```
magic<1, 6>( [](auto x) { f<x.value>(); } ); // [1, 6) i.e. {1,2,3,4,5}
```

with the implementation

```
template<int beg, int end, class F>
constexpr auto magic(F f)
{
    //                                              v~~~~~v
    return magic<beg>(f, make_integer_sequence<int, end-beg>{});
}
```

Note the weird `+1` disappears.

Comment: `discard` needs to be variadic, no?

Comment: @jrok Indeed, fixed now, tested, works, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ca0829dfc522972)

Comment: `template<class T> void discard(T&&...) {}` That's the old-school elipsis you've got there, not pack expansion (it's legal to omit the comma, go figure!). Correct: `template<class ...T> void discard(T&&...) {}`

Comment: @jrok Ouch, you're right m( Wouldn't matter, though, as the passed argument is always an `int`. Maybe it's even better to use an ellipsis, as that doesn't need to instantiate a template.

Comment: Agreed, if we're sure it's always a scalar type.

Comment: I don't get it yet, but it looks like your solution actually works without any wrapper classes or anything like this. Didn't think it was possible at all. That's what I call magic.

Comment: @Vasily There's a wrapper class, it's created implicitly by writing the lambda-expression ;) I'll add some explanation..

Comment: Implicit compiler constructions isn't something I care about :)

Comment: Your use of `discard` means that the functions aren't necessarily called in order. The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified in general.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb True, fixed.

Comment: this works with c++14 only right? no way to make it work with c++11?

Comment: @user3770392 In C++11 you don't have polymorphic lambdas (i.e. lambdas with `auto` parameters), but you can use custom function objects with `operator()`-templates (like `struct Foo{ template<class T> void operator(){ f<T::value>(); } };`). The integer sequence tools can be written in C++11, they're part of C++14's Standard Library.

Comment: @dyp thank you. Ok about the auto and the indices. What I've not understood is how to pass that kind of function you're talking about. The ::value should work on std::integral_constant, but I don't see any in that code..

Comment: @user3770392 The `integral_constant` appears in my answer in the function `constexpr void magic(F f, integer_sequence<int, Is...>)`, in the parameter pack expansion.

Answer (score 5):

Using reified functions and template template arguments:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int I> class f {
public:
  static void call() {
    std::cout << I << '\n';
  }
};

template<template<int I> class X, int I, int J> class magic {
 public:
  static void call() {
    X<I>::call();
    magic::call();
  }
};

template<template<int I> class X, int I> class magic<X,I,I> {
public:
  static void call() {
    X<I>::call();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  magic<f,2,6>::call();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting solution. I'm talking about using of "template<int I> class X" template parameters. I didn't even know it is possible. Is it possible to use the same mechanics for function, not class? Or it can only be used with classes?

Comment: @Vasity, As you can't pass functions as template parameter you can't pass functions like this. The magic "function" is implemented as a class so you can use template specialisation.

Comment: I've tried this solution but my program prints "2" hundreds of times and then it crashes. You should edit your answer by modifying:  magic::call(); into magic<X, I+1, J >::call();